# Facebook Flow (instead of TypeScript) with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, flowtype

I'm getting started with Native Script. I know that TypeScript is a first-class citizen in NativeScript and I can use it simply doing `tns install typescript` and it works. But if I decide use Facebook Flow instead of TypeScript, is there a way to do this? Or is Facebook Flow incompatible with NativeScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use anything that generates JS.   CoffeScript, TypeScript, etc.

Based on a quick look of flow you annotate the JS files directly; so you need to add the [flow-remove-types](https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/flow-remove-types/) plugin and activate run it each time before you go to build your app.

The biggest issue I can see with this process; is you will need to keep your "typed" js in a separate folder, than the normal folders.

If you know JS well enough you can easily create a prepare hook which will do this all automatically for you (this is how TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Sass, etc all work) using the [nativescript-hook](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-hook), this allows you to hook into the CLI so that when you do a `tns run android/ios` it will automatically create the proper JS files.